# Wordpress (Wordpress popular posts plugin) query

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post, plugins

Can I use:

```
<?php
if (function_exists( 'wpp_get_mostpopular' )) {
  wpp_get_mostpopular('range=weekly&order_by=views&limit=8');
}
?>
```

Inside custom template (inside query posts) to make query with own template output:

```
<?php query_posts(????????); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="myclass">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail'); ?></a>
</div>
```

Please help me with this, so I don't have to edit plugin and plugin's css while I have my ready just to query posts by this plugin.

Thanks.

Plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/

Answer (score 0):

@alen imeko as far as i have understoody your requirment, why you need this plugin, you just need to show the most popular post where ever you need to, You just need to set the post to sticky and call the sticky post using the same query post method then it will automatically render your specified post at the respective place.
For this just go to post to make it sticky, at the top above the publish/update button you will see an option **visibility** click the edit part of it and you will the options will slide down check the checkbox having text **Stick this post to the front page** and after that you just need to perform query.

```
      $args =  array( 
    'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'post_date' => 'DESC',
    'cat' => your category id
    );

     query_post($args);
 ?>
```

Then you need to simply use the while loop for that the same way you do in wordpress.